# Caching issue Angular IIS Cloudflare

Tags: angular, iis, single-page-application, browser-cache, cloudflare

I have an angular 6 app with routing which is build with angular cli and served on IIS, config is pretty basic, url-rewrite is setup so that page refreshes work etc.

The problem I'm seeing is that sometimes when the app is updated, browsers get a 304 response for the index.html (even though it has changed) and will load the old index.html from memory/disk cache, and then try to load the bundles which do not exist anymore, the response for these bundles is a 200 and contains the new index.html which the browser proceeds to try and run as JS and throws an error.

Disabling caching in the web.config to troubleshoot has no effect as the 304 seems to take priority.

The strange thing is when the site is updated visiting host.com might return the new index.html and everything is fine while visiting host.com/login may return the 304 and cause the issue. This varies between browsers, some do the same thing but the opposite way around.

The requests go through cloudflare which I do not have control over the configuration of (someone else manages this for the client). Could cloudflare be the issue or is it more likely to be something in my IIS configuation?

Here is the web.config currently:

```html
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="api rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="api/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="/api/(.*)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was adding a rule to my web.config to disable caching just for the index.html like this:

```html
<location path="index.html">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Seems to have fixed the issue, the bundles are still cached but when we deploy new builds the clients always get the latest index.html so get pointed to the correct bundle. There is probably a better way.

It seemed to only be an issue when the url rewrite occured quickly after visiting the site, maybe some race condition?, i.e. the home page is /login, so visiting host.com/login it was always fine and would get the latest index.html, but visiting host.com resulted in a cached index.html then angular router redirecting to /login right away, which then makes another request and the url rewrite returns 304. Still not entirely sure what is happening but disabling the caching of index.html has solved the issue for now.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend leaving old items sitting around for a while - in case people still have the site open. Or else you need to handle redirecting to the new site when you detect a 404 during a failed lazy-load navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue.  For me, I was setting the cache information for static content in the web.config, but it was also getting applied to the index.html.  You're likely relying on the Cloudflare caching rules -- see if they can add a rule so the index.html isn't cached (or is cached for a very short time).